# Microst Visual C++ runtime library dlgcore.cpp at line 589

Tags: c++, c, forms, mfc, dialog

I am trying to create an mfc dialog input form when a button is pressed. The dialog used to work. Now all I get is Microsoft Visual C++ runtime library Error.

Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\mfc1404.dll

File:

d:\agent...\dlgcore.cpp

line 589

(see attached pic).

**the on press button code**

```
void CmfcacqDlg::OnBnClickedAcquire()
{

    CString lastName;
    CString gender;

    CDialog InputFormDlg;
    InputFormDlg.DoModal();
    ....
```

**InputFormDlg.cpp**

```
// InputFormDlg.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "pch.h"
#include "InputFormDlg.h"
#include "mfcacq.h"
#include "mfcacqDlg.h"
#include "afxdialogex.h"


// InputFormDlg dialog

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(InputFormDlg, CDialog)

InputFormDlg::InputFormDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=nullptr*/)
    : CDialog(IDD_INPUTFORM, pParent)
    , firstName(_T(""))
    , lastName(_T(""))
    , gender(_T(""))
{

}

InputFormDlg::~InputFormDlg()
{
    
}

void InputFormDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_FIRST_NAME_TEXT, firstName);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_LAST_NAME_TEXT, lastName);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_GENDER_TEXT, gender);
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(InputFormDlg, CDialog)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

**InputFormDlg.h**

```
#pragma once


// InputFormDlg dialog

class InputFormDlg : public CDialog
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(InputFormDlg)

public:
    InputFormDlg(CWnd* pParent = nullptr);   // standard constructor
    virtual ~InputFormDlg();

// Dialog Data
#ifdef AFX_DESIGN_TIME
    enum { IDD = IDD_INPUTFORM };
#endif

protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
    CString firstName;
    CString lastName;
    CString gender;

    CString GetFirstName() const { return firstName; }
    CString GetLastName() const { return lastName; }
    CString GetGender() const { return gender; }
    void SetFirstName(const CString& value) { firstName = value; }
    void SetLastName(const CString& value) { lastName = value; }
    void SetGender(const CString& value) { gender = value; }
};
```

**.rc file**

```
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated resource script.
//
#include "resource.h"

#define APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 2 resource.
//
#include "afxres.h"

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#undef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// English (United States) resources

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_ENU)
LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US
#pragma code_page(1252)

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Dialog
//

IDD_INPUTFORM DIALOGEX 0, 0, 310, 177
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "Dialog"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    EDITTEXT        IDC_FIRST_NAME_TEXT,88,22,88,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL
    EDITTEXT        IDC_LAST_NAME_TEXT,88,40,88,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL
    EDITTEXT        IDC_GENDER_TEXT,88,58,88,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,253,156,50,14
    PUSHBUTTON      "Cancel",IDCANCEL,199,156,50,14
    LTEXT           "First Name",IDC_FIRST_NAME,28,22,40,8
    LTEXT           "Last Name",IDC_LAST_NAME,28,40,40,8
    LTEXT           "Gender",IDC_Gender,28,58,40,8
END


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// DESIGNINFO
//

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
GUIDELINES DESIGNINFO
BEGIN
    IDD_INPUTFORM, DIALOG
    BEGIN
        LEFTMARGIN, 7
        RIGHTMARGIN, 303
        TOPMARGIN, 7
        BOTTOMMARGIN, 170
    END
END
#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// AFX_DIALOG_LAYOUT
//

IDD_INPUTFORM AFX_DIALOG_LAYOUT
BEGIN
    0
END


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Icon
//

// Icon with lowest ID value placed first to ensure application icon
// remains consistent on all systems.
IDR_WITTERN             ICON                    "Wittern-Group-Logo.ico"

#endif    // English (United States) resources
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// French (France) resources

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_FRA)
LANGUAGE LANG_FRENCH, SUBLANG_FRENCH
#pragma code_page(1252)

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Dialog
//

IDD_ABOUTBOX DIALOGEX 0, 0, 235, 55
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "About Enrollment"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 0, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,178,32,50,16,WS_GROUP
    ICON            IDR_WITTERN,IDC_STATIC,11,17,20,20
    LTEXT           "MFC Enrollemnt",IDC_STATIC,40,10,119,8,SS_NOPREFIX
    LTEXT           "Copyright © Wittern 2020-2020. All rights reserved.",IDC_STATIC,40,25,119,8
END

IDD_MFCACQ_DIALOG DIALOGEX 0, 0, 272, 196
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
EXSTYLE WS_EX_APPWINDOW
CAPTION "Fingerprint Enrollment"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 0, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    PUSHBUTTON      "Enumerate",IDC_ENUMERATE,23,16,77,14
    COMBOBOX        IDC_LIST_DEVICES,106,16,119,68,CBS_DROPDOWN | CBS_SORT | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
    PUSHBUTTON      "Get descriptor",IDC_GET_DESCRIPTOR,23,34,77,14
    PUSHBUTTON      "Acquire",IDC_ACQUIRE,23,52,77,14
    CONTROL         "",IDC_DISPLAY,"Static",SS_BLACKFRAME | WS_BORDER,105,33,122,118,WS_EX_STATICEDGE
    EDITTEXT        IDC_STATUS,108,160,117,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_READONLY
    CONTROL         "",IDC_PROGRESS_QUALITY,"msctls_progress32",PBS_SMOOTH | PBS_VERTICAL | WS_BORDER,233,34,13,116
END


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// DESIGNINFO
//

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
GUIDELINES DESIGNINFO
BEGIN
    IDD_ABOUTBOX, DIALOG
    BEGIN
        LEFTMARGIN, 7
        RIGHTMARGIN, 228
        TOPMARGIN, 7
        BOTTOMMARGIN, 48
    END

    IDD_MFCACQ_DIALOG, DIALOG
    BEGIN
        LEFTMARGIN, 7
        RIGHTMARGIN, 260
        TOPMARGIN, 7
        BOTTOMMARGIN, 187
    END
END
#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// AFX_DIALOG_LAYOUT
//

IDD_ABOUTBOX AFX_DIALOG_LAYOUT
BEGIN
    0
END

IDD_MFCACQ_DIALOG AFX_DIALOG_LAYOUT
BEGIN
    0
END


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Icon
//

// Icon with lowest ID value placed first to ensure application icon
// remains consistent on all systems.
IDR_MAINFRAME           ICON                    "Morpho.ico"


#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// TEXTINCLUDE
//

1 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "resource.h\0"
END

2 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "#include ""afxres.h""\r\n"
    "\0"
END

3 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "#define _AFX_NO_SPLITTER_RESOURCES\r\n"
    "#define _AFX_NO_OLE_RESOURCES\r\n"
    "#define _AFX_NO_TRACKER_RESOURCES\r\n"
    "#define _AFX_NO_PROPERTY_RESOURCES\r\n"
    "\r\n"
    "#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_FRA)\r\n"
    "LANGUAGE 12, 1\r\n"
    "#pragma code_page(1252)\r\n"
    "#include ""mfcacq.rc2""  // non-Microsoft Visual C++ edited resources\r\n"
    "#include ""afxres.rc""     // Standard components\r\n"
    "#endif\r\n"
    "\0"
END

#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Version
//

VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
 FILEVERSION 5,25,1,0
 PRODUCTVERSION 5,25,1,0
 FILEFLAGSMASK 0x3fL
#ifdef _DEBUG
 FILEFLAGS 0x1L
#else
 FILEFLAGS 0x0L
#endif
 FILEOS 0x4L
 FILETYPE 0x1L
 FILESUBTYPE 0x0L
BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "000004b0"
        BEGIN
            VALUE "CompanyName", "Wittern Group"
            VALUE "FileDescription", "MFC Enrollment"
            VALUE "FileVersion", "5.25.1.0"
            VALUE "InternalName", "Enrollment.exe"
            VALUE "LegalCopyright", "Copyright © Wittern 2020-2020. All rights reserved."
            VALUE "OriginalFilename", "Enrollment.exe"
            VALUE "ProductName", "Wittern Fingerprint Enrollment Application"
            VALUE "ProductVersion", "5.25.1.0"
        END
    END
    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        VALUE "Translation", 0x0, 1200
    END
END


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// String Table
//

STRINGTABLE
BEGIN
    IDS_ABOUTBOX            "&About mfcacq..."
END

#endif    // French (France) resources
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 3 resource.
//
#define _AFX_NO_SPLITTER_RESOURCES
#define _AFX_NO_OLE_RESOURCES
#define _AFX_NO_TRACKER_RESOURCES
#define _AFX_NO_PROPERTY_RESOURCES

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_FRA)
LANGUAGE 12, 1
#pragma code_page(1252)
#include "mfcacq.rc2"  // non-Microsoft Visual C++ edited resources
#include "afxres.rc"     // Standard components
#endif

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#endif    // not APSTUDIO_INVOKED
```

Comment: Switch the "Stack Frame'" combobox on the Visual Studio toolbar to your code to see the line of your code that caused the issue.

Comment: @drescherjm I am very new to VS and MFC. Can you please provide more details?

Comment: There is a combo box on the top toolbar of Visual Studio called "Stack Frame" change it to your code after the you break into the debugger for the exception. This means going down the items in the combo box till you find your code and not Microsoft functions. The first line you hit that is your code was the one that triggered the bug although there may have been other bugs in your code before this line.

Comment: FWIW, that line 589 is an ASSERT: `INT_PTR CDialog::DoModal()
{
 // can be constructed with a resource template or InitModalIndirect
 ASSERT(m_lpszTemplateName != NULL || m_hDialogTemplate != NULL ||
  m_lpDialogTemplate != NULL);`

Comment: Including both `"stdafx.h"` and `"pch.h"` is strange and suspicious, as they both imply precompiled headers, old and new style.

Comment: I found the solution. 
1) My ID (IDD_INPUTFORM) in the constructor did not match the ID in the resource view -> properties of the dialog. 
2)I built the dialog wrong. Here is how I build it now,
 InputFormDlg dlg;
 dlg.DoModal();